# Dúvida: como arrumar o UnicodeEncodeError no Python?

Tags: python, unicode

Desde que mudei de máquina, ando tendo o seguinte problema com o interpretador *Python*:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Todas strings que envia e recebe está se transformando em unicode. **Como posso arrumar isto?**

Comment: Pode postar o código que está causando o problema?

Comment: Vocês está usando python 2 ou python 3? existe alguma chance de ter mudado a versão de 3 para 2 quando você mudou de máquina? já tentou colocar _# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-_ no topo do arquivo ?, Você poderia colocar parte do código aqui na pergunta (principalmente onde usa o caracter unicode) ?

Answer (score 1):

***Abaixo*** está uma tradução adaptada de uma resposta feita no **StackOverflow** (o original) para um problema semelhante ao seu. Pode ver a pergunta original [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error/3224300#3224300) com suas respostas.

---

### Tradução:

**Provavelmente** você esteja tentando imprimir um texto que contenha caracteres Unicode estrangeiros - *em relação ao básico ASCII 128* - que pode ser nosso idioma mesmo. Tente *codificar a string Unicode como ASCII 256* primeiro:

```
unicodeData.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

O '*ignore*' vai dizer para pular estes caracteres.  Da documentação do Python:

```
>>> u = unichr(40960) + u'abcd' + unichr(1972)
>>> u.encode('utf-8')
'\xea\x80\x80abcd\xde\xb4'
>>> u.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ua000' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'abcd'
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'replace')
'?abcd?'
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'&#40960;abcd&#1972;'
```

Talvez seja útil ler o artigo "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)"*, que acho ser um bom tutorial para o que está acontecendo.  Depois de ler, você vai parar de sentir que está só achando o que fazem os comandos (ao menos, é o que ocorreu comigo).

---

### NOTA:

*Existe uma tradução do artigo mencionado, como indicado pelo @jsbueno. Tal artigo é de autoria de Joel Spolsky e a tradução é de Paulo André de Andrade. Veja [aqui](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29).*

Comment: O artigo linkado na resposta é de fato uma introdução bem completa ao Unicode - e todos (todos, nao importa que linguagem estejam usando, ou se acham que não precisam de acentuação) devem le-lo. Há uma tradução do mesmo aqui:
http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29

Comment: (mas essa resposta está longe de ser esclarecedora, completa ou boa  - aborda parte do mesmo problema, sim - mas só isso)

Comment: @jsbueno vou editar a resposta para colocar essa tradução! :)